# Discussion platform with calendar and contacts

Tags: gratis, open-source, calendar, forum, self-hosted

I'm looking for a software package that can do the following:

- Discussion platform (aka forum / persistent chatbox(es))
- Calendar (with features like doodle)
- Contact book / User listing

So far I have found baikal as a Calendar/Contacts solution but it doesn't have a doodle-like feature and discourse as a forum. But I'm hoping there is a more complete solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Open Atrium](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium), which is a [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal) "distribution". Some more details about it (from the linked page):

> A new architecture for Drupal 7 that is built upon [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) and [Panopoly](https://www.drupal.org/project/panopoly) and intended as an extensible collaboration framework. Adds the ability to have private "sections" within a collaboration space with granular access control. Drag/drop layout control with dozens of widgets that can be placed on dashboards and landing pages. Comes with Discussions, Events, Files, Issue tracking, and Document Wiki out of the box, along with the dashboards to manage it all.

To be complete, there is also [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com), a SO-site dedicated to Drupal, which has tons of questions (and great answers) about topics related to [Open Atrium](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium).